# sparkline with a different data set in SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2008

Hello i am working on sparkline in SSRS.

I have a table1 with dataset1. 
I have to embed another dataset2 with in this table1. I have to show the dataset2 vales in a sparkline.

Can you please let me on how to do this.

I am getting this error

```
The sprakline has a detailed member with in a inner member. Detailed member can only contain static inner member


Dataset1 : keyid,keyword,metricname,currentmonthdata,previousmonthdata,12monthsAgoData.
Dataset2 - keyid,month1data,month2data,month3data,month4data
```

I want to show this dataset2 motnh's data on sparkline

Comment: Are you able to give a few example rows of data for the two datasets?

Comment: Dataset1 : keyid,keyword,metricname,currentmonthdata,previousmonthdata,12monthsAgoData.          In Dataset2 - keyid,month1data,month2data,month3data,month4data            I want to show this dataset2 motnh's data on sparkline

Answer (score 0):

You can create new report, add spark line into that and then embed that report as sub report. 
I hope that will help you.